# Loopback; polymorphic belongsTo and hasManyThrough depending on owner type

Tags: relationship, loopbackjs

I have a Bid object. A Bid can belong to a Customer or to a Carrier (polymorphic belongsTo).

Also, a Customer may belong to a Carrier (if a Customer belongs to a Carrier, he can't bid), and the Customer is the one who executes the service they are bidding for.

So, if a Carrier makes a Bid, he has to assign customers to it. In this scenario, many customers can have many bids, but they are not the applicants.

I wonder how is the best way to do this. It's like a conditional relation.

I tried this in **bid.json**:

```
"relations":{
  "bidder":{
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "polymorphic": true
  },
  "customers": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "customer",
    "foreignKey": "customerId"
  }
}
```

**customer.json**:

```
"relations": {
  "bids": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "Bid",
    "foreignKey": "bidderId",
    "polymoprhic": "bidder"
  }
  "carrier": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "Carrier",
    "foreignKey": "carrierId"
  },
  "assignments": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "Bid",
    "foreignKey": "bidId"
  }
}
```

**carrier.json**

```
"relations": {
  "bids": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "Bid",
    "foreignKey": "bidderId",
    "polymoprhic": "bidder"
  }
  "carrier": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "Customer",
    "foreignKey": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a new entity "Assignment". This way, if a carrier makes a bid, he can assign customers to it. If the customer is the bidder, he assigns himself automatically

**bid.json**

```
"relations":{
  "bidder":{
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "polymorphic": true
  },
  "assignments": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "assignment",
    "foreignKey": "bidId"
  } 
}
```

**customer.json**

```
"relations": {
    "bids": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Bid",
      "foreignKey": "bidderId",
      "polymoprhic": "bidder"
    }
    "carrier": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Carrier",
      "foreignKey": "carrierId"
    }, 
    "assignments": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Assignment",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    }
  }
```

**carrier.json**

```
"relations": {
  "bids": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "Bid",
    "foreignKey": "bidderId",
    "polymoprhic": "bidder"
  },
  "customers": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "Customer",
    "foreignKey": "carrierId"
  }
}
```

**assignment.json**

```
"relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "licitacion": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Bid",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```